# Tornado performance issue with MySQLand Redis

Tags: asynchronous, websocket, tornado, python-asyncio, tornado-redis

I have a tornado server running with MySQL for DB and Redis for cache. I am using web socket to send/receive data. My code is like this:

**Server**

```
import logging
import os.path
import uuid
import sys
import json

import tornadis
import tormysql
import tornado.escape
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
from tornado import gen
from tornado.concurrent import Future
from tornado.options import define, options

@gen.coroutine
def getFromDB(query):
    with (yield dbPool.Connection()) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            yield cursor.execute(query)
            datas = cursor.fetchall()
            return datas
    return None

@gen.coroutine
def getFromCache(cmd):
    pipeline = tornadis.Pipeline()
    pipeline.stack_call(cmd)
    with (yield cachePool.connected_client()) as singleClient:
        redisResult = yield singleClient.call(pipeline)
        if isinstance(redisResult, tornadis.TornadisException):
            print("Redis exception: %s"%(redisResult))
        else:
            return redisResult

async def getData(dbQuery, cacheQuery):
    waitDict = {}
    if dbQuery:
        waitDict['db'] = getFromDB(dbQuery)
    if cacheQuery:
        waitDict['cache'] = getFromCache(cacheQuery)
    resultList = []
    if len(waitDict) > 0:
        await gen.multi(waitDict)
        if 'db' in waitDict:
            dbRes = waitDict['db'].result()
            if dbRes:
                for eachResult in dbRes:
                    changeRes = someFunct(eachResult) 
                    resultList.append(changeRes)
        if 'cache' in waitDict:
            cacheRes = waitDict['cache'].result()
            if cacheRes:
                for eachResult in cacheRes:
                    changeRes = someFunct(eachResult) 
                    resultList.append(changeRes)
    return resultList

class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    SUPPORTED_METHODS = ("GET")

    def open(self):
        print("Socket open:%s"%(self))

    def on_close(self):
        print("Socket closed:%s"%(self))

    async def on_message(self, inp):
        if requestForData:
            ret = await getData(dbQuery, cacheQuery)
            self.write_message(ret)

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/sock", SocketHandler),
        ]

define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
app = Application()
app.listen(options.port)
print("PORT:%s"%(options.port))
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

I am using `tornadis` for Redis and `tormysql` for MySQL.
I am running this setup on amazon linux instance m5.large with 2vCPUs memeory:8Gib.

**Client**

I am trying to simulate the traffic using web socket. The code is like this:

```
import sys
import json
import asyncio
import websockets

def getData():
    for i in range(100):
        async with websockets.connect(SOCKET_URL, extra_headers=extraHeaders) as websocket:
            for i an range(100):
                await websocket.send("get data")
                reply = await websocket.recv()
                print(reply)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(getData())
```

I am running multiple instance of the client.
The server is running good but its able to handle only 25 connections. After 25 connections the delay for the reply from the server increases. I want server to reply to be very fast. How do I decrease the delay for the response? So is there any problem in the code?

Comment: First, you'll have to figure out where the bottleneck is. Easiest way to do that would be by testing your functions separately, that is, by writing unit tests. A longer way would be to put `print` statements after every yield and `await`. This would also tell you which `yield/await` is taking too long to resolve.

Comment: @xyers I have future returned by function and I am waiting for those. Do I need to still test individual function for the delay? Does the async functions block?

Comment: If you're waiting for futures, then the delay for the response makes sense. Now you seem to be contradicting your question.

Comment: @xyers Got the point